# is there way to print subtotal and total on jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

is there way to print subtotal and total on jasper report in detail band?
I am iterating the field according to dataSource.
The format look like :

```
Id   | Date |  Card No | Vehicle No | Amount

1     1/3/2011  ABC1      33493S       39
      12/3/2011                        40
                         Total         79

2     2/4/2011  ABC2      34433G       20
                         Total         20                    
---------------------------------------------
                         Total         119
```

thanks

Comment: What is the exact question? How to get total of some field's values or how to get total in detailed band? Or both are your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a field with the subtotal or total variable and then assign it's evaluation time to the appropriate group. So if you have a group called 'Date' then create a new field and set the evaluation time for that field to Group -> Date.